Document/Asset Scoring in SharePoint
is there an out of the box solution or feature that can be used to set up a scoring system for documents in SharePoint? I saw that SharePoint has a built-in rating feature, but it looks limited to just the on-prem version. Similarly, I looked into Azure Semantic Ranking, but that is a service I'd rather not use.

Are you looking for a scoring feature in SharePoint Online? If yes, please refer to this article: How to Rate and Like items and documents in SharePoint
